# DAVMail for Lotus Notes

Tags: imap, lotus-notes, webdav, caldav

My company uses Lotus Notes (8.5 version of the client). Sigh...

Anyway, I've installed the client on Ubuntu and OS X. It works, slowly. It also hogs memory and has no integration with the OS. I'd like to use the native Mac Mail client (or any other client). So I'm looking for something like DAVMail for Lotus Notes.

I recall installing a small program on my Windows box that was supposed to do exactly this. Unfortunately it did nothing more than freeze up my Windows box. I can't seem to find this program again. Does anyone know the name of the program I'm looking for?

BTW, my company disabled the IMAP and SMTP integration on the Domino server and won't re-enable it.

Comment: Well, without SMTP enabled there's no chance of getting support for outbound messages unless you know of an internal relay server that you can use. Do they have POP3 enabled? Do they have HTTP enabled to support iNotes (browser-based mail client)? Do they support Lotus Notes Traveler for mobile clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't something like DAVMail for Notes, as far as I know.

Have you tried configuring it to use basic mode instead of standard mode? That will make it use significantly less resources.

Beyond that, consider using iNotes on the web if you don't have need for application access.

If your company has Citrix, it's often faster to run Notes through Citrix than natively as well.

Comment: In my subsequent searching, I've found no evidence of the DAVMail-like program for Notes I mentioned--perhaps I dreamt it. I think yours is the answer.